# IE9 Forcing quirks mode & cannot find a solution

Tags: html, internet-explorer

IE9 is forcing Quirks mode and I have tried out a few solutions to no success

I have tried adding :  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`

However this doesn't seem to fix the issue - even if it is placed directly underneath `<head>`

Here is the top of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- the "no-js" class is for Modernizr. -->
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Availability</title>
    <link href="<%= CommonHelper.GetApplicationLocation() %>portal.css" type="text/css"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <LINK href="<%= CommonHelper.GetApplicationLocation() %>National.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-10">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= CommonHelper.GetApplicationLocation() %>favicon.ico" />
        <LINK href="<%= CommonHelper.GetApplicationLocation() %>css/new-styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <LINK href="<%= CommonHelper.GetApplicationLocation() %>mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR" />
    <meta content="C#" name="CODE_LANGUAGE" />
    <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript" />
    <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="quYroxU0ZWi8YjEB9xL8j79VCAhHrSalFUnPFexYjxI" />
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: for what it's worth, the "chrome=1" part is for installing ChromeFrame. ChromeFrame is discontinued. You can safely drop it from your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the simple `<!doctype html>` declaration at the top of your HTML file. This is for HTML5, and it is most probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the url in the doc type see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms535242(v=vs.85).aspx for a table of when standards mode is triggered or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

As commented, you may as well just use the html5 doctype. It's very succinct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I'd recommend HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) as it's short, easy to remember and switches all post-1999 browsers into Standards mode (not Almost Standards, like Transitional 'flavors' of HTML4/XHTML1).